# how tcp sliding windows tells the sender the window size?

Tags: tcp

A simplified example is the receiver has buffer of 3 segments, and then send both ACK and a window 3 to the sender.
The sender will then send 3 segments.

My question is when the receiver gets the first segment of the 3, it will send back ACK and a window size 2. In this way, the sender will send 2 more segment. But at this stage, the receiver does not have enough buffer, which will require size 5.

Do i understand something wrong about the sliding window? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The receive buffer has *bytes,* not 'segments'.
2. In your example, after receiving one byte, it will send a window size of two; the sender can send up to two more bytes; and they will fit into initial buffer of 3 along with the first byte. I don't know where you get the 5 from.

Comment: I use segment instead of bytes to simplify. Let's talk in 'byte' way. The sender already sent 3 bytes at the beginning because the first window is 3. If the second window is 2, the sender will send 2 more. As you can see, 3+2=5. Thanks for your response.

Comment: 1. There's nothing simple about being wrong. 2. The sender doesn't send two more. You started by sending three. The receiver acknowledged one and sent a window size of two. That lets the sender send two more after the one being acknowledged. It has already done that. It can't send any more until it gets a receive window that permits it.

Comment: Sorry, i still do not get it. The sender sent 3 bytes first, and then got a window size of 2(assumed that the second byte and third byte not arrived yet). Then the sender can send two more bytes(the fourth byte and fifth byte), right?

Comment: The window size is the measure of how many unacknowledged bytes can be in flight. In your example, there are two unacknowledged bytes in flight, which completely accounts for the advertised window, so the sender cannot send any more.